# SQL script that automatically detects free appointments in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-scripts

In my application, users are able to check if a specific appointment is free. So they choose a specific date and time and specify the length of the appointment.

An SQL script checks if there is already an appointment at the specific time. What I want to do now is to offer further appointment options to the user.

Example:
User selects `2013-08-24 18:00:00` as start date and `2013-08-24 18:30:00` as end date. The appointment is already taken but options have to be offered:

- offered appointment can be at the same day
- offered appointment can be some hours before or after the prefered appointment
- offered appointment can also be the same date in one week

This is my table (at least the important part of it):

```
CREATE TABLE `ios_appointments` (
  `appointmentId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `start` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `end` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  ...
)
```

Example data:

```
| appointmentId  |  start              |  end
=========================================================
|  1             | 2013-08-24 18:00:00 | 2013-08-24 18:30:00
|  2             | 2013-08-24 15:00:00 | 2013-08-24 16:00:00
|  3             | 2013-08-24 09:00:00 | 2013-08-24 12:00:00
```

If the specified length of the appointment is 2 hours, the proposed appointments should be something like:

```
|  start              |  end
=========================================================
| 2013-08-24 12:00:00 | 2013-08-24 14:00:00
| 2013-08-24 13:00:00 | 2013-08-24 15:00:00
```

How can I accomplish some kind of "smart" sql script?

Comment: Do you have the possibility to modify the schema? Because your table is not normalized, and this can make queries less easy...

Comment: There is no "smart" sql script. You'll have to write queries for each case and check the results yourself.

Comment: The schema can be modified if necessary.

Comment: why not add an IsTaken field and mark the field true when an appointment is taken?

Comment: Free appointments are not in the table. Only taken ones, so a isTaken field can not be applied because it would always be true.